# Explore shapeless's `Last` Type Class

Tags: scala, shapeless

I typed out, more or less, the `Last` type class of `shapeless`'s `Last`:

```
import shapeless.{HList, HNil, ::}

trait Last[H <: HList] {
  type Out
  def last(in: H): Out
}
```

Then, I typed out the, as I understand, type class instances of `Last` for `HList`:

```
object Last {
  type Aux[L <: HList, O] = Last[L] { type Out = O }

  // arrived at the truly `last` item, i.e. `H`
  implicit def singleLast[H]: Aux[H :: HNil, H] = new Last[H :: HNil] {
    override type Out = H
    override def last(in: H :: HNil): H = in.head
  }

  // I believe this is the inductive step
  implicit def hlistLast[H, T <: HList, OutT]
  (implicit lt : Last.Aux[T, OutT]): Aux[H :: T, OutT] =
    new Last[H :: T] {
      type Out = OutT
      def apply(l : H :: T): Out = lt(l.tail)
    }
}
```

However, I don't understand why it fails to compile:

```
[error] /Users/kevinmeredith/Workspace/shapeless-sandbox/src/
      main/scala/net/ops.scala:17: net.Last.Aux[T,OutT] does not take parameters
[error]       def apply(l : H :: T): Out = lt(l.tail)
[error]                                      ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

How can I fix this compile-time error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual shapeless implementation of `Last` looks like:

```
trait Last[H <: HList] {
  type Out
  def apply(in: H): Out
}
```

You changed `apply` to `last`, but in `hlistLast` you are still trying to use `apply` (both by defining it and using it on `lt`):

```
def apply(l : H :: T): Out = lt(l.tail)
```

The compiler error comes from trying to use `lt.apply` when it doesn't exist. It would have been more helpful in this case if the compiler first told you that `last` was left unimplemented.

Comment: Hmm. So how can I fix it?

Comment: Rename your `apply` in `hlistLast` to `last` or rename `last` to `apply` in the trait/`singleLast`.